# AWS RDS status while creating the RDS via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I am creating the RDS via AWS CLI using

```
create-db-instance
```

RDS is getting created but I want to wait until the RDS comes to "available" state so that I can execute the remaining part of the script. I am not sure how can I achieve that.

Comment: Try a while loop with http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html

Comment: How do I test the state?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `wait`ers as provided by the AWS SDK in its CLI. Specifically, you want to wait until RDS DB instance becomes available. Look at [`db-instance-available`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/wait/db-instance-available.html).

```
aws rds wait \
    db-instance-available \
    --db-instance-identifier "your-rds-instnace-id"
```

Comment: This is working but is there a way I can print the status such as if it is in creating state or modifying statue or backing up state every 20 seconds or so.

Answer (score 4):

Never tried this. But the following CLI is what you need:

```
aws rds wait db-instance-available --db-instance-identifier <value>
```

> Wait until JMESPath query DBInstances[].DBInstanceStatus returns
>   available for all elements when polling with describe-db-instances. It
>   will poll every 30 seconds until a successful state has been reached.
>   This will exit with a return code of 255 after 60 failed checks.

Answer (score 4):

These days, you should use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to call AWS.

The command would be:

```
aws rds create-db-instance ...
```

Then, you could call a *waiter:*

```
aws rds wait db-instance-available ...
```

See:

- [create-db-instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/create-db-instance.html)
- [db-instance-available](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/wait/db-instance-available.html)

Comment: Thanks, John.
Is there a way I can pull the DB state (Creating/modifying/backingup) in real time every 20 seconds? So that I can print it over the screen.

Comment: `aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier xx --query DBInstances[*].DBInstanceStatus`